# Which type of og:type value allows the meta property product:retailer_item_id?

Tags: angular, facebook-graph-api, single-page-application, meta, angular-universal

[Facebook's sharing debugger tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing) gives me the following error when scraping:

> Extraneous properties specified
>
> The following properties are specified on the webpage but NOT supported for the specified 'og:type': product:retailer_item_id

I've successfully tracked all meta tags [required for the Facebook catalog feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/product-catalog/update-options), but I need the `retailer_item_id` meta property to satisfy their [catalog data feed requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/product-catalog/update-options).

I've tried values `product` and `og:product` for the `og:type` content value, but this error is still present.

```html
<meta property="product:retailer_item_id" content="123" />
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD" />
<meta property="product:price:amount" content="25" />
<meta property="product:condition" content="new" />
<meta property="product:availability" content="in stock" />
<meta property="product:brand" content="My Company" />
<meta property="og:type" content="og:product" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.placecage.com/200/300" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Foo" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Bar" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Best Site Ever" />
```

OG's docs seem outdated and info is scattered throughout Facebook's own documentation - anyone have experience with this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue, did yu find out what the tag was?

Comment: Seems fine on my end. Actually I compared the fields and they work. So maybe try to move the og meta at the beginning and then output the product data. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="og:product" />
```

To this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="product.item" />
```